# How to write a wrapper in javascript?

Tags: javascript

My level of javascript is close to 0 so if this question is documented elsewhere then I have not found it and will gladly accept a link to the docs.

I have a javascript function that does a login. It's in debug stage for the moment and the library used is `abaaso`:

```
/* login */
var calledUrl = baseapi + "user/login/" + credentials;
calledUrl.post(
    function (content) {

        console.log("success" + JSON.stringify(content, null, 4));
    },
    function (e) {

        console.log("it failed! -> " + e);
    },
    {
        "username": "user@example.com",
        "password": "passwd"
    },
    {
        "Accept" : "application/json"
    }
);
```

This works if I load it in a browser inside an html page.

In the example above I would like to be able to create a wrapper that abstracts most of it and just call the wrapper function passing it the bare minimum, something like

```
login("user@example.com", "passwd");`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you mean, but I guess you could do something like:

```
window.loginToFoobar = function(username, password) {
  /* login */
  var calledUrl = baseapi + "user/login/" + credentials;
  calledUrl.post(
    function (content) {
        console.log("success" + JSON.stringify(content, null, 4));
    },
    function (e) {
        console.log("it failed! -> " + e);
    },
    {
            "username": username,
            "password": password

    },
    {"Accept" : "application/json"}
  );
}

// Then call the login function from wherever you want:
loginToFoobar('user@example.com', 'passwd');
```

Comment: it looks good, I'm not sure what the 'window.' part is though?

Comment: It's not really necessary, just a convention I use when creating variables that are global, I assign them to the 'global' window object. You could in this case also call it as window.loginToFoobar(). Feel free to remove the '.window' part.

Comment: ok it's interesting. I am trying this right now in an html file between <script> and </script>, I load it in the browser with firebug enabled and it does not give any error but neither any output. I'm not sure if it is executed. The original example is executed. Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you sure your other scripts (especially abaaso) are executed first?

Comment: the structure is: <head> import abaaso, <body> <script> pasted your example, and after everything else just before </script> call to the function. If I paste the old example instead and remove the call then it is executed.

Comment: just out of curiosity I tried to remove the 'var' before declaring the function. And it gets executed. I don't know the difference between implicit and explicit declaration in javascript.

Comment: ahhhhhh, of course, I'm so sorry, that first var should not be there, I've updated the example.

Comment: So, just to be clear, you could do `var foo = function()` OR `window.foo = function()`. The first one is declaring a variable within the 'current' scope, the second will declare it as a property of the window object.

Comment: ok great, it works. I have simplified the question to match your answer. I will create new questions for the rest.